# Как найти площадь прямоугольника или помогите найти ошибку в коде

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, canvas, ecmascript-6

Есть два нарисованных прямоугольника на канвасе. Как найти площадь их области пересечения которая создает новый прямоугольник?или помогите найти ошибку в коде

```
    const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    class Rectangle {
        constructor(x, y, height, width) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
        }

        get area() {
            return this.width * this.height;
        }

        intersectDetails(baseSquare, square) {
            const left = Math.max(baseSquare.x, square.x);
            const width =
        Math.min(baseSquare.x + baseSquare.width, square.x + square.width) - left;
            const top = Math.max(baseSquare.y, square.y);
            const height =
        Math.min(baseSquare.y + baseSquare.height, square.y + square.height) - top;

            return {left, width, top, height};
        }


        draw() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = randomColor();
            ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
   }

    const rectangle1 = new Rectangle((Math.random() * canvas.width) / 2,
          (Math.random() * canvas.height) / 2,
          (Math.random() * canvas.height) / 2,
          (Math.random() * canvas.width) / 2);
   const rectangle2 = new Rectangle((Math.random() * canvas.width) / 2,
        (Math.random() * canvas.height) / 2,
        (Math.random() * canvas.height) / 2,
        (Math.random() * canvas.width) / 2);

   rectangle1.draw();
   rectangle2.draw();

   const figure = new Rectangle().intersectDetails(rectangle1, rectangle2);
   console.log(figure.area);
```

Comment: Причем здесь canvas? нужно просто посчитать по формуле, или Вас интересуют противоестественные способы типа "посчитать кол-во пикселей в результирующем изображении"?

Comment: Stranger in the Q, Нужно посчитать кол-во пикселей в результирующем изображении

Comment: Это можно, но это будет не точный способ

Comment: Это не критично

Comment: А почему не подходит математический способ? Вы не закрашиваете области, для подсчета закрашенных пикселей необходимо заливать фигуры, а не рисовать их контуры, как мне кажется и использовать globalCompositeOperation вроде difference, чтобы покрашенные во второй раз пиксели отличались цветом от оригинальных цветов прямоугольников

Comment: Я пробовал решить задачу традиционным методом, но у меня видимо где-то ошибка в коде

Comment: я доберусь до компа и напишу ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собрал на телефоне сниппет из svg, я надеюсь это не принципиально, просто так меньше кода для визуализации...

```js
let rects = document.querySelectorAll("rect");

let r1 = getRect(rects[0]);
let r2 = getRect(rects[1]);

let l = Math.max(r1.l, r2.l);
let r = Math.min(r1.r, r2.r);
let b = Math.min(r1.b, r2.b);
let t = Math.max(r1.t, r2.t);

rects[2].setAttribute("x", l);
rects[2].setAttribute("y", t);
rects[2].setAttribute("width", r-l);
rects[2].setAttribute("height", b-t);

function getRect(rect){
    let l = +rect.getAttribute("x");
    let t = +rect.getAttribute("y");
    let r = l + +rect.getAttribute("width");
    let b = t + +rect.getAttribute("height");
    return {l,t,b,r}
}
```

```html
<svg id="test">
  <rect fill=wheat x=5 y=5 width=50 height=60></rect>
  <rect fill=teal x=45 y=35 width=70 height=40></rect>
      <rect fill=red></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: а как найти площадь этого прямоугольника?

Comment: @NazarFernos перемеожить ширину и высоту)